# WSO2 API Manager - Can't start the server

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I would like to install and use WSO2 API Manager on my computer but I have some issues when I try to start the server.

I use the API Manager 3.0.0 version and I've installed it through .msi for Windows.

Here are the errors that come when I try to start the server with a clean setup :

```
[Broker] BRK-1001 : Startup : Version: 0.11 Build: 90784:90849
[Broker] MNG-1001 : Startup
[Broker] MNG-1004 : Ready : Using the platform JMX Agent
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672
[2020-04-01 11:18:18,692]  INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5672
[Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672
[2020-04-01 11:18:18,706]  INFO - listening [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8672
[Broker] BRK-1004 : Qpid Broker Ready
[2020-04-01 11:18:25,147]  WARN - RevokedJWTTokensRetriever Failed retrieving revoked JWT token signatures from remote endpoint: Connection refused: connect. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2020-04-01 11:18:25,147]  WARN - KeyTemplateRetriever Failed retrieving throttling data from remote endpoint: Connection refused: connect. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2020-04-01 11:18:25,161]  WARN - BlockingConditionRetriever Failed retrieving Blocking Conditions from remote endpoint: Connection refused: connect. Retrying after 15 seconds...
[2020-04-01 11:18:35,958] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.1.42:9711
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://192.168.1.42:9711
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59) [org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 192.168.1.42:9711. Connection timed out: connect
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:75) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:285) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:144) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212) ~[commons-pool_1.5.6.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent_5.2.12.jar:?]
    ... 6 more
[2020-04-01 11:18:39,720] ERROR - QpidServiceComponent Wait until Qpid server starts on port 5672
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:101) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:240) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:558) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:454) ~[?:?]
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAMQPServer(QpidServiceComponent.java:463) [org.wso2.carbon.andes_3.3.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.startAndesBroker(QpidServiceComponent.java:423) [org.wso2.carbon.andes_3.3.3.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent.activate(QpidServiceComponent.java:132) [org.wso2.carbon.andes_3.3.3.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.internal.ServerAdminServiceComponent.activate(ServerAdminServiceComponent.java:99) [org.wso2.carbon.server.admin_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:544) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:529) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:234) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:85) [org.wso2.carbon.core_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222) [org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:113) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:985) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:151) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:866) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:525) [org.eclipse.osgi_3.14.0.v20190517-1309.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81) [org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.400.v20130418-1354.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60) [org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.400.v20130418-1354.jar:?]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40) [org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.1.400.v20130418-1354.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1122) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1077) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:971) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4868) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5177) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) [?:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.service.ExtendedStandardService.startInternal(ExtendedStandardService.java:52) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [tomcat_9.0.22.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.start(CarbonTomcat.java:113) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:167) [org.wso2.carbon.tomcat_4.5.1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

I have already tried to put an offset on ports, still not working.
I have checked port use through netstat and none of WSO2 ports are already used.

Thank you for your help.

Best Regards,

Edit : I finally found how to solve my problem. It seems that localhost is not the default address and so I had to stipulate it manually in the deployment.toml file for throttling and amqp broker.

Here is what I added :

```
[apim.throttling]
receiver_url = "tcp://localhost:9611"
receiver_auth_url = "ssl://localhost:9711"

[broker.transport.amqp]
bind_address = "localhost"

[broker.transport.amqp.default_connection]
enabled = true
port = 5672
```

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file that deployment.toml located at

```
./repository/conf/deployment.toml
```

I found the file using below command on osx.

```
find ./ -name "deployment.toml"
```